# Lyx Single Column

Tags: lyx, two-column

In Lyx, one has the option of making 'Two-column' document by selecting the corresponding option in the 'Text Layout' section of the document settings. Is there any way of disabling this for a few pages? So if I have a document that's two column, is there a way to make the third page and only the third page single column only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the commands `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` to switch between modes. Both commands will cause a new page to start before the change in mode.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\onecolumn
\lipsum[1-6]
\twocolumn
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Depending on the reasons you have for wanting the single column, there may be better means of achieving what you want. For example, there are ways to make tables, figures and equations span two columns within a two column document.

To make a floating figure or table span two columns, you can use the `{figure*}` and `{table*}` environments.  If you do so, it is best to load the [`dblfloatfix`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dblfloatfix) package to improve placement options.

Alternatively, the [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/multicol) package allows you to put selected parts of text in a one column document into multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Ctrl-L` for invoking the TeX mode and then insert `\onecolumn`. Going back to the two column layout is the same with inserting `\twocolumn`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `LaTeX` package `singlepage` may have the answer. That allows you to change formatting for just one page.

Comment: CTAN does not list a `singlepage` page.

Comment: @lockstep My apologies. It's been a while since I used `LaTeX`. I was thinking of the `fancyhdr` package -- it has the option to do different layouts for different pages. If you still can't find the answer in the `fancyhdr` docs let me know and I'll look harder.